# P value and rejection

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

Could someone please explain the logic of the reasoning behind why we reject the Ho if the alpha exceeds the p value

What I understand is that alpha is the probability of making a type 1 error if Ho is true.

P value is the likelihood of getting a value more to the right or left of your test stat if the Ho is true (probability of getting a test stat that favors Ha more)

So if alpha>p value = reject Ho

Then it must mean that if the probability of making an error while Ho is true is larger than the probability of getting a value more the to the right of your test statistic then reject Ho. How does that logic add up? Could someone explain the reason behind the why we reject Ho?

For example if the chance of picking a value that might lead to a improper conclusion while Ho is true exceeds the chance of getting a value more the right than my test statistic I would reject Ho - how does that work?

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Without a diagram or more clear context right or left is vague and easy to misinterpet.   It's common to use the phrase $z_{x}$ or $t_{x}$ is more extreme or less extreme than $z_{critical}$ or  $t_{critical}$.  Remember, $z_{critical}$ or  $t_{critical}$ ares based on alpha, but $z_{x}$ or $t_{x}$ are typically derived from your sample.
Or maybe for simplicity, simply specify that everything in this exercise is right of the population mean?  In that case, more extreme would be further right.

Comment: Also, what results did you get when you searched for this?
I won't vote on your question, but it's likely to be closed as a duplicate question.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3836139/comparing-p-value-and-type-1-error-to-reject-the-null-hypothesis?rq=1  among other questions which are already answered.

Comment: What's your understanding of *rejecting $H_0$*?